# Show Excel in my own App

Tags: android, excel, show

Is there any way to show Excel file in my application? Like if you want to show webpage you will use Webview. Or the only way is open another app by Intent?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after a fashion.  You can use [jexcelapi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/), a java library to read/write Excel files.   I've used this in one of my apps to import and export data using spreadsheets.  It was a classroom app, and all the data had to end up in spreadsheets for the school anyway.

You'll have to put the data into your app via TextView or WebView or some other method as you can't simply run excel on your Android device without an office file reader.  Not all phones have those.